# Cache/Buffer RAM Full

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, debian

Good Morning,

we have a Debian server 11 on Google Cloud Platform.

On this Server we have installed only apache2 service but we have about 10 sites installed.

These sites use php 7 and they were created with Symfony 2.8.

The site's databases is hosted on another server, in another nation.

We have noticed that after two days the server has 27GB cache/buffer used.

[image]

Can anyone advise us why we have the cache so full?

Could it be the many queries?

Thank You so much

We have enabled OPCACHE and infact it delete oldest session but we have not solved the problem.

Comment: It depends. But you could start by seperating the applications onto different servers. Also, PHP 8 has way better performance than PHP 7, and Symfony 2.8 is outdated since years

Comment: I'm not a Linux guru but I'd say almost all your RAM is available. Linux tries to make the best use of your memory, there's no point it keeping it unused, that'd be a waste of resources. https://chronicler.tech/why-does-linux-report-100-memory-usage-all-the-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about that.

Linux uses most of the unused memory for cache and buffers. This is a kind of optimizing. It leaves some memory free to allow fast assigning if a program needs memory.

Current status:

- 402 MiB used for programs (the most relevant value!)
- 3 GiB currently unused
- 27 GiB currently occupied for system optimization (buffers and cache). If free-memory becomes to small, the system will free memory from here.